# Calculating normalized karma

Tags: algorithm

How could I calculate a normalized value of karma (value between 0 and 1), from the karma of users in my system?

The normalized value should reflect the value of the user's karma relative to all other users.

I think I would probably have to include the average and standard deviations of all karma's somehow, but I can't seem to come up with the right formula.

Any help?

Comment: I think you might want to put a "time" limit on that karma.  That way recent people get the karma but someone from 2 years ago, won't count.

That way, new people are not just permeinately in the bottom rank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 min_karma = min(karmas)
 max_karma = max(karmas)
 normalized = (karma - min_karma) / (max_karma - min_karma)
```

This has the property that the user(s) with karma = min_karma get a normalised karma of 0, and users with karma = max_karma get 1. Others are linearly distributed in between. You will have to handle separately the special case that all users have the same karma.

If you want a non-linear distribution you could use a logarithmic function:

```
 normalized = (log(karma) - log(min_karma)) / (log(max_karma) - log(min_karma))
```

It is important in this case that the karma can never fall below 1, as this could skew the results.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Consider a situation where 100 users have a low karma distributed around 10, and only 1 user has a high karma of 100. I would expect the normalized values to take into account the fact that only 1 user has a high karma, and therefore give users with for example 15 karma a better than linear advantage. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, there is no max karma, as karma gets added for certain actions that can be done indefinately (such as getting high ratings for a review you posted)

Comment: You could take the logarithm of the score if you want a non-linear distribution.

Comment: @EdanB: The max_karma refers to the *current* max, which changes as people get more karma.

Answer (score 2):

you would want to calculate the percentile that each user belongs to. in mysql, you can do it like this:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,105223,105278#msg-105278

```
rank / total
```

where rank is the number of users with lower karma.